# An open source headless CMS or blog engine with an option for eCommerce module

Tags: open-source, web-apps, cms, ecommerce, blog

I am looking for a headless CMS or blog engine for a personal site. I am planning to write a lot and to get a lot of feedback.
There probably would be a need for an eCommerce solution.

I do not like Wix and WordPress sites, they both seem too rigid to me, so they are definitely not an option. Also at this stage, I very much prefer a free solution.
Besides, I want to have full control of my site workings.
I have some JS/HTML/CSS knowledge and am not afraid to delve deeper, so learning is not an issue.
However, I would like to avoid a very steep learning curve.

I have tried to find a similar question and answer, but most of the answers that I have found are 3-4 years old. If I have missed something please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Strapi is a good choice for your use case. Free, open-source and self-hosted and you can use modern dev tools like React and node.js on your frontend and delve deeper.